# Folders have been deleted with no reason in CFEclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana

We work with **CFEclipse** (with **Aptana** plugin) in two computers on the same project which is running on a local server.
Yesterday some folders have been deleted with no reason. No one did delete the files and folders but they've gone.
someone has an idea why did it happen?

Comment: What does mean local server, local repository?

Comment: a server which running our local website. the folders are stored within this computer. we use the folders/files of the website through local file system.

Comment: IMO it is hard to recover deleted files, but you should start using repository (git,svn) to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: what is repository, and why should i use it? we work on this way: we change the same files and folders and running them in our local website server. i cannot run a page through my computer because i don't have a server installed int it, and i want to change the same file located in the server.

Comment: See this
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/145583/should-i-use-a-code-repository-if-i-am-the-only-one-working-on-a-project and this: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/